# Using GridSearchCV with interval

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

When using Grid search for classifiers in python using this function GridSearchCV() imagine we have an interval of parameters to tune form 1 to 100 how are we able to specify that (1:100 doesn't work ) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should pass arguments to GridSearchCV() function :

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(), n_jobs=1)),
])

parameters = [

    {'clf__estimator__kernel': ['rbf'],
     'clf__estimator__gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
     'clf__estimator__C': [1, 10]
    },

    {'clf__estimator__kernel': ['poly'],
     'clf__estimator__C': [1, 10]
    }
     ]

grid_search_tune = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=2, n_jobs=3, verbose=10)
```